# Tor Secret Key isn't working on local host server

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, configuration

I'm new to Tor, and so far I've managed to get public & secret keys. But when I try to run my public key on my Tor browser, it says "Unable to Connect" and the sub-line is "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost."

I've followed the instructions many times and also watched some videos but no luck. And almost everytime I configured Tor, I see this message "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.", but still can't access my onion site.

So please guide me where I'm making a mistake or what steps do I need to follow to configure  Tor browser correctly to do the task. Also do I need Xampp/Wampp local server for this? If yes! than I'm already using Xampp. After messing with it for many days it is still confusing to me. So please guide me with best practices or solution. thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your hidden service is correctly configured in your Tor, but your web server has its hostname set to localhost and to return a Content-location or Location header. See if you can config your web server to not care about hostname or set it to your onion address.

Comment: Thanks Jobiwan for your reply, Yes I got it fixed and can now open localhost with public key on my Tor Browser. But how can i publish it online now or in simple words how others can access my website with this key?

Comment: If you can reach your hidden service through Tor, then anyone can. If you're asking how to _advertise_ your hidden service, that might be worth a new question of its own, but I don't have a good answer to that one.

Comment: I'm referring just like we upload normal sites in hosting servers like Godaddy or Hostegator, do we need upload this too? If yes than how?
f
I'm wondering how other users can open my onion site, like i use to open like duckduckgo etc.

Comment: Are you saying that other people **can not** connect to your hidden service now? Have you tested it? As I wrote before: _If you can reach your hidden service through Tor, then anyone can._

Comment: Yes I've tested it on Other Computers, and also ask other people to open it via Tor Browser, and yes they can navigate to same page where i can.

So thanks for assisting me :)

Comment: @UmairRazzaq CMS's aren't really on-topic here. There isn't really anything that would prevent them (any of them) working through Tor. If you can make your second question more about Tor, please ask it as a new question instead of commenting here. Thanks. I removed the previous comments.

Comment: and can you tell us how to configure the webserver to the onion url?
i am using savant webserver.
that would be great as i have the same issue that the first post