# Tor can't connect to localhost hidden service

Tags: onion-services, firefox, onion-routing

So I just downloaded Tor and I'm trying to set up a hidden service. Not going so well. I'm using Savant web server, and can open up 'localhost' on Chrome, but I put:

```
HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\Sellar\tor_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

in my torrc file, started up Tor again(Browser bundle, no Vidalia), tried connecting to the hostKey it gave me(and it did give me one), but it says firefox is unable to establish a connection to the server at localhost. I set Savant to localhost and port 80.
Is there something I can change to make this work? is 127.0.0.1 supposed to be my IPv4 or Default Gateway or something, or is it always 127.0.0.1? Anything else that comes to mind that might help?

Comment: Do you see any relevant lines in your log file? Or maybe first set up logging and then have a look.

Comment: You need to wait enough time before trying to access your HS. Tor needs to advertise it to the directory servers, which sometimes takes time, depending on some factors like busy directory servers or busy Tor client on your PC (doing something other when you start it). So, if everything is configured right, just wait.

Comment: Alright. @Jens Kubieziel Where are the log files?

Comment: @YaakovSchectman: Tor Browser doesn't log by default. But you can edit the `torrc` to set it up. Navigate to the directory where you extracted TBB and then to `Data\Tor`. Insert a line like `Log notice torlog.txt` and restart Tor. Now you should find some lines inside `torlog.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

> ... it says firefox is unable to establish a connection to the server at localhost. ...

Your issue is similar to this one:
[Tor Secret Key isn't working on local host server](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/tor-secret-key-isnt-working-on-local-host-server)

I believe the solution to your issue is in my first comment to that question:

> your web server has its hostname set to localhost and to return a Content-location or Location header. See if you can config your web server to not care about hostname or set it to your onion address.